# Is there something like Jasmines iit() for Qunit?

Tags: jasmine, qunit

In Jasmine when your test set contains a test called with iit() it will only run this/these test/s. This saves you the hassle of creating a dedicated test set if you are only focusing on a small subset of tests during development.

Is there a similar shortcut like this in Qunit? (I'm using Karma as my test runner)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975998/is-it-possible-to-run-a-single-test-using-qunit-inside-karma