# Is it possible to run a single test using QUnit inside Karma?

Tags: testing, qunit, karma-runner

Jasmine has `iit()` and `ddescribe`, and Mocha has `it.only` and `describe.only`, but I can't see any way to get QUnit to focus on running a single test.

The QUnit UI allows you to run a single test, but I can't see how to get this to work inside Karma, because it doesn't display the QUnit UI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. It works fine for me, but YMMV.

Download qunit-karma-setup.js, qunit-karma-launch.js from [here](https://gist.github.com/ftokarev/8096825)

Then, in your Gruntfile:

```
config.set({
  frameworks: ['qunit'],
  files: [
    'your-app-files-here/**/*.js',
    'qunit-karma-setup.js',
    'your-tests-here/**/*.js',
    'qunit-karma-launch.js'
  ]
});
```

Now, you can use omodule(), otest(), oasyncTest() functions to run only the selected modules or tests respectively.

Answer (score 2):

QUnit is not well designed for this, but **you can improve it!**

The filtering mechanism of QUnit is `validTest` function that read `QUnit.config.filter` (string, name of a test). See https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/src/core.js#L820

**There are two problems:**

1. it only allows selecting one test,
2. you need to know the selected test name in advance (because the tests are filtered when being created).

**Suggest changing QUnit to:**

- filter using a custom "filter" function (the default implementation can do what the current `validTest` does),
- filter the tests when executing (means, collects all the tests first)

Then, implementing inclusive tests will be simple ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [`only`](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit/only). Taken from the docs:

```
test('my test 1', function (assert) { ... });

only('my test that will be run exclusively now', function (assert) { ... });
```

So instead of using word `test`, you use `only`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on the top of your test file

```
var ttest = test;
test = function() {}
```

And rename the test you want to run to `ttest`. Looks clumsy, but simple and works well.